# Save the state of a WKWebView (iOS)

Tags: ios, memory, wkwebview

I am currently working on an application that will have multiple `WKWebViews` running simultaneously, think of tabs in a browser, however it seems that if I have about 5 `WKWebView` instances running at least one of them will go blank and show a white screen at some point. I am sure this has to do with some memory management going on in the background that I don't have control over.

My question is this: If I wanted to save the state of a `WKWebView` between switching screens, how would I go about this?

My initial thoughts would be to save the `HTML`, `CSS`, and `JavaScript` to some sort of local storage and reload the page with the "cached" memory before doing a full reload of the page.

I have been looking at the open source project for Chrome and it seems they are doing something with Objective-C++, but I am not sure why.

If anyone has any thoughts or knowledge on this it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not clear enough, anyhow let me give you some suggestions,
Even though if you switch between you 5 WKWebviews their state will remain same, so no need to save the state manually.

Regarding Plain webpage Issue while loading:

Implement,

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
didFailProvisionalNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation 
      withError:(NSError *)error;
```

Inside this method reload the webview whenever Load Fails.

Comment: Thanks I did implement something like this and it works it's just not as smooth as I would hope, I think what I will try is capturing a screenshot when I navigate away from the page, and displaying it while it reloads if it needs too. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: But what if I wanted to go deeper into managing my own memory, can you point me in the right direction?